# Using the To_Date function is not converting to the expected format

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I'm trying to convert a char (output from a substr operation) into a dateTime format using TO_DATE with the following format - hh24:mi:ss.

The output of the substr looks fine but as soon as I run it through the TO_DATE function it converts every row for this column into 01-MAR-22.

To demonstrate I have the following:-

**SUS_TIME2** shows what I get back from the SUBSTR and it looks fine at this point. **SUS_TIME3** then shows what I get back after running it through the TO_DATE function, this where it converts it to 01-MAR-22

```
,SUBSTR((s.resolve_date-suspend_date),-16,9) sus_time2

,TO_DATE(SUBSTR((s.resolve_date-suspend_date),-16,9), 'hh24:mi:ss') sus_time3
```

[image: example]

Can anyone see what's going on here please? Thanks

Comment: @HoneyBadger - Oracle dates *always* have a time component, even if it's midnight.

Comment: @HoneyBadger That is completely wrong. An Oracle `DATE` is a binary data type consisting of 7 bytes representing century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second and it **ALWAYS** has those components.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the data types of `s.resolve_date` and `suspend_date` and an explanation of the entire problem (and not just this last step with `TO_DATE`). My guess is that one (or both) of them is a `TIMESTAMP` data type and subtracting them is giving you an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` data type and you are trying to find the time component of the interval. In which case, the question is an XY-problem and you probably do not need to use `TO_DATE`.

Comment: @MT0 
This is part of pre-existing query and all i'm trying to do is format the data so that when it's exported to Excel sorting works correctly. If I view the sus_time2 column in Excel i'm not able to sort it by smallest to largest as it doesn't recognise it as a time, instead it just gives me the option to sort A to Z. 

suspend_date and resolve date come about earlier in the query in the select statement.

select
,transaction_date_lcl suspend_date
,lead(transaction_date_lcl) over(partition by lcunit_id order by transaction_date_lcl) resolve_date

Answer (score 1):

Dates are stored in an internal representation and do not have any intrinsic format. What you are seeing is how your client is choosing to format the actual date value as a string for display, using your session's NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting (not always the case, but this is SQL Developer, so it is here.)

When you call `to_date()` with *only* the time components it defaults the date part to the first day of the current month, which is why you are seeing March 1st. That is a bit [buried in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/nlspg/datetime-data-types-and-time-zone-support.html#GUID-4D95F6B2-8F28-458A-820D-6C05F848CA23):

> If you specify a date value without a time component, then the default time is midnight. If you specify a date value without a date, then the default date is the first day of the current month.

But it is setting the time properly on that date, which you can see by either explicitly converting the date back to a string:

```
to_char(<your date>, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

or by changing your session:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=201fc35c1c1e81460b03507e3f409568)

But you should not rely on NLS settings for anything except ad hoc queries; someone else running your code may have different settings. And only convert back to a string at the last moment when you have to display the value in a particular format - store it and pass it around as a native date.

Oracle doesn't have a time-only data type, so if you really only care about the time part then you can use a date (either defaulting to current month, or using an explicit fixed date) and ignore the date part; or potentially use an interval; or use the number of seconds the time represents (i.e. 0-86399). Which is suitable depends on what you'll use the value for.

It looks like you might be substringing the result of subtracting two timestamps; in which case (a) you already have an interval, and (b) you probably need to allow for that difference to span more than one day. You can also extract the individual time components directly from an interval value. So I'd question whether your approach is really appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be calculating `s.resolve_date-suspend_date` which gives you an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` data type (implying that one or both of `s.resolve_date` or `suspend_date` is a `TIMESTAMP` data type) and then using `SUBSTR` to extract the time component of the data type and trying to convert that to a date and then display the time component.

Don't do that as using `SUBSTR` is fragile as it depends on the number of decimal places that the `INTERVAL` has which, in turn, will depend on the number of fractional seconds that the `TIMESTAMP` values have.

---

Just pick a date and add the interval to it and then format it as string to display it:

```sql
SELECT s.resolve_date,
       suspend_date,
       TO_CHAR(
         DATE '1900-01-01' + (s.resolve_date-suspend_date),
         'hh24:mi:ss'
       ) sus_time
FROM   table_name s
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (resolve_date, suspend_date) AS
SELECT CAST(SYSTIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP(6)),
       CAST(TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP) AS TIMESTAMP(6))
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | RESOLVE_DATE | SUSPEND_DATE | SUS_TIME |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2022-03-25 12:59:15.223445 | 2022-03-25 00:00:00.000000 | 12:59:15 |

---

From [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71616889/using-the-to-date-function-is-not-converting-to-the-expected-format/71617391#comment126573695_71616889):

> all i'm trying to do is format the data so that when it's exported to Excel sorting works correctly.

That really is an XY-problem. You can solve it in Excel by either specifying the column format as a time when you import the data into Excel or right-click on the column header and "Format" the column picking the "time" data type with the correct format model.

You can also output the time as a fraction of a day with a numeric data type and then Excel can format it as the correct time using either:

```sql
SELECT s.resolve_date,
       suspend_date,
       MOD(CAST(s.resolve_date AS DATE)-CAST(suspend_date AS DATE), 1) AS sus_time
FROM   table_name s;
```

or

```sql
SELECT s.resolve_date,
       suspend_date,
       TO_CHAR(DATE '1900-01-01' + (s.resolve_date-suspend_date), 'SSSSS')
         / 86400 AS sus_time
FROM   table_name s
```

Which both output:

> | RESOLVE_DATE | SUSPEND_DATE | SUS_TIME |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2022-03-25 13:16:40.204461 | 2022-03-25 00:00:00.000000 | .5532407407407407407407407407407407407407 |

Which may not be human readable in that format but Excel will reformat it in a time column to `13:16:40`.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f6d8e8e7181d15f7355edb9cefa5e2e1)*